# Get e-mail from Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want create a login system with Facebook on a project, but the graph API never return the e-mail adress.

This is the code to start the connexion with the good permission for email:

```
$helper = $facebook->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['email']; // Optional permissions
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://example.com/login.php?auth=fb', $permissions);
```

And in login.php, this is the code :

```
$response = $facebook->get('/me?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,picture,email&scope=public_profile,email', $accessToken);
$fbResponse = $response->getGraphUser();
print_r($fbResponse);
```

The `print_r` return the profil picture URL, the last and first names, but the email is `null` even if I try with my main facebook account.

Can somebody can help? It's very important to get an e-mail to create an user on the database.

Comment: be aware that you may not always get an email. not all users use an email to login at facebook. there are some threads about this on stackoverflow already.

Comment: @luschn Even if I try to connect with my own facebook account, I can read the auth permission with the mail adress liked to my account, but it return null